# Company's right to insist on personal info

Tags: privacy

I have a maintenance contract with Scottish Hydro for my boiler. Whenever I call them, or they call me, about a repair or service, they demand my name, DOB and address (even when I provide them with an account number). They insist this is "for data protection". They refuse to deal with me if I don't respond. Why on earth is such info needed for a boiler repair? It has nothing to do with financial aspects of my account. Can they continue to demand this info?

Comment: This looks like a legal question...

Comment: They could probably continue doing this. However, nothing forces you to keep doing business with them.

Comment: As @techraf pointed out, this is a question that depends almost absolutely on your country's legislation. In the case of my country, as long as they notify you about the usage intended for the data, they can collect what they want. If the data is not essential for the process (e.g. if you don't need them to know your address because you go to them), you could simply give out fake data. Or, if it's such a big deal, present a legal request to get service without disclosing data. In any case, it is an off-topic question here.

Comment: Name and address would be things that you would already have told the company in order to get service, so it is shared information. I'm not sure why you would have a problem with sharing that info with them. DOB is, potentially, another matter. But if you have already shared that with them in order to set up service, I'm not sure what the issue is with providing it over the phone.

Comment: The problem is of course, since virtually every company does this, it's very easy for fraudsters to get the information too. Even worse is the way some companies will call and demand details before they tell you why they're calling (and sometimes, who they are). In the latter case, I refuse to take the call; in the former, I just hope there's no MITM at the exchange.

Comment: @AndréBorie If only that was true; AFAICT, the industry as a whole works like that, so the choices are 1. Put up and shut up, or 2. Stop using gas/electricity/water/phones/internet

Answer (score 2):

Given that the provider you're dealing with is Scottish Hydro, it's reasonable to assume you're in Scotland.  Scotland is covered by the [Data Protection Act 1998](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29/contents) for which the principles are that data must be:-

> - used fairly and lawfully
> - used for limited, specifically stated purposes
> - used in a way that is adequate, relevant and not excessive
> - accurate
> - kept for no longer than is absolutely necessary
> - handled according to people’s data protection rights
> - kept safe and secure
> - not transferred outside the European Economic Area without adequate protection

As to if they're breaking the law or not it's arguable, while they are not taking action that will cost you money they are taking actions which may affect your policy (for example number of call-outs per year etc) or may be accessing a part of the system where they can view or update payment details so they'd want to be sure it was someone authorised to do so.

That said, there are security risks which their procedures open their customers up to (for example miscreants could contact a large number of people posing as Scottish Hydro and obtain personal information) so they certainly have plenty of room for improvement in their data handling procedures and that's definitely worth raising with someone at a high level (you should ask to speak to or for contact details of their nominated 'Data Controller' and you should get a named contact).

It is likely that the people you've spoken to are not properly aware of the law or their rights and obligations under it.  This is common among call centre staff to use data protection as an excuse even when you point out that they've made a huge privacy blunder.  They probably have a script which will not allow them to continue without the information even if they agreed the request was excessive use of your personal data.  They don't have the power to do anything about it, most of the time they are outsourced and don't directly work for the company you're paying anyway.

> If you think your data has been misused or that the organisation holding it hasn’t kept it secure, you should contact them and tell them.
>
> If you’re unhappy with their response or if you need any advice you should contact the Information Commissioner’s Office (ICO).
>
> ICO helpline
>   Telephone: 0303 123 1113
>
> The ICO can investigate your claim and take action against anyone who’s misused personal data.
>
> [source: gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/data-protection/make-a-complaint)

---

And money talks as pointed out in the comment:- nothing forces you to keep doing business with them. – *André Borie*

Comment: If only that was true; AFAICT, the industry as a whole works like that, so the choices are 1. Put up and shut up, or 2. Stop using gas/electricity/water/phones/internet

Comment: That's not the situation I've had with other providers of similar services here like british gas - they've been pretty good unless we need to discuss billing (even when they owed us a fair chunk of cash).

Comment: Guess it's luck of the draw then.